# How to keep connection in app in background mode?

Tags: ios, swift, background, voip

I have XMPP messenger in my app and when user presses home button and minimize the app, my XMPP stopping to receive new message signals and does not show any alert.

In iOS 9 I solved that problem with turning on `Voice over IP` checkbox. But in iOS 10 I started to receive this warning:

```
Legacy VoIP background mode is deprecated and no longer supported
```

So with this solution my app worked iniOS 9, but stopped to receive messages and show message alerts in background mode in iOS 10.

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: you need to change it to Push Notifications?

Comment: See "Tips for Developing VoIP Apps" https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13. While this isn't technically VoIP, the basic recommendation is the same. Yes, that means you must manage push notifications which requires a server and is more complicated. But that is the supported mechanism and Apple is removing the other.

Comment: By turning on VOIP would not resolve your problem, to keep connection with XMPP server and get messages while your app is in background or terminated state, you actually need to implement pushkit. Refer https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification